# Why this SQL statement outputs one or more rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, rownum

My intention by the following SQL statement is to select just one tuple randomly from
join result of tables `MovieExec, Movie and Studio`.
But this SQL statement outputs one tuple, sometimes two or more tuples.
Because of the condition `r = trunc(dbms_random.value(1,6))`,
I thought there cannot be two or more tuples from the following SQL statement.

```
select name
from (select e.*, rownum r 
      from  (select movieexec.name, count(*) 
             from movieexec,studio,movie where certno = presno and producerno = certno 
             group by movieexec.name having count(*) = 1) e
      )
where r = trunc(dbms_random.value(1,6));
```

But, if the last where condition is `r = (select trunc(dbms_random.value(1,6)) from dual where rownum =1 )`,
it will output just one tuple always.
I wonder why the first SQL statement can show one or more tuples.

Answer (score 2):

MTO has definitely shown how to rewrite the query using correct syntax.  But that is not the question you are asking.  You are asking why you can get more than one row.  I should note that you can also get 0 rows -- or any number up to 6 (although that would be very rare).

What is happening?  The basic answer is that the random value is being calculated on each row.  So, consider six rows like this -- and the random value generated:

```
  r     random
  1       5
  2       5
  3       3
  4       1
  5       2
  6       6
```

In this case, the third and the sixth rows match the `where` conditions.  So, what you are really doing is choosing a random subset of the first six rows, where the random value happens match `r`.

It is also worth noting that `where rownum = 1` will return one row.  But because of how `rownum` works, `where rownum = 2` returns no rows -- because `rownum = 1` has to be returned before `rownum` is incremented to `2`.

Comment: But that rows will not be returned because first row fails `where` condition and `rownum` cannot be sparse.

Comment: @astentx There is no filter on the middle of the nested queries where `ROWNUM` is generated so they will all be numbered. The filter is on the outer-most sub-query.

Comment: I appreciate your helpful comment.
I understand HOW my SQL statement can show multiple tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I you are on Oracle 12, you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` with a random ordering:

```sql
SELECT e.name,
       COUNT(*) 
FROM   movie m
       INNER JOIN studio s
       ON ( m.certno = s.presno )
       INNER JOIN movieexec e
       ON (  e.producerno = m.certno )
GROUP BY
       e.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

*(You can also give the tables aliases and use ANSI joins rather than using the legacy comma joins.)*

Your query can be re-written as:

```sql
select name
from (
  select e.*,
         rownum r 
  from   (
    select e.name
    from   movie m
           INNER JOIN studio s
           ON ( m.certno = s.presno )
           INNER JOIN movieexec e
           ON ( e.producerno = m.certno )
    group by e.name
    having count(*) = 1
    order by dbms_random.value()
  ) e
)
where r = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0afb7bc9908945e536923a173ea55893)*

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried your solution.
But, Just wonder why my SQL statement shows two or more tuples randomly.

Comment: [ANSI join syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABCGEDH) has no brackets.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, it does. You need to go into the Condition documentation where you [find this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Compound-Conditions.html#GUID-D2A245F5-8071-4DF7-886E-A46F3D13AC80) which shows that compound conditions supports surrounding brackets.

Comment: No, conditions don't require brackets, and your link includes examples of conditions like `WHERE salary = 2500` without any brackets. Nothing in the [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Conditions.html) section suggests we have all been writing `WHERE` clauses wrong all these years. (`m.certno = s.presno` isn't a compound condition.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Conditions do not require brackets, however, it is syntactically valid to wrap conditions in brackets so stating that it "has no brackets" (and implying that it should not have brackets) is not true. Brackets are optional and allowed and the documentation I linked to explicitly includes the `( condition )` syntax (which is a classed as a compound condition and can be directly reached from [this part of the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-E9EC8434-CD48-4C01-B01B-85E5359D8DD7)).

Comment: We are of course free to put redundant brackets in all kinds of places. We could write `select (1) from dual` for example, but they are not called for by the syntax.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You are entitled to your opinion and your own preferred syntax. I prefer to include the brackets (which are allowed syntax) for additional clarity when reading the query. This is not code-golf so we do not have to strive for the minimal number of characters and if 2 extra characters makes it, in my opinion, more readable then I will use those 2 extra characters. We could equally argue that unnecessary white space is not required by the syntax trees but I hope that you are not saying that we should only ever separate keywords by a single space character.